# TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I have this program running to "sniff" traffic on my network but the first problem i run into is it gives it to me in some formatted code like hex. so i try to convert the code but it doesn't work since it's a tuple so i convert the tuple into a string. I get this error code:

```
$ python sniffer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sniffer.py", line 24, in <module>
    output1 = convertTuple(output)
  File "sniffer.py", line 8, in convertTuple
    output = functools.reduce(operator.add, (tup))
TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes
```

And here is my full code:

```
import binascii
import struct
import socket
import functools
import operator

def convertTuple(tup):
    output = functools.reduce(operator.add, (tup))
    return output

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind(("192.168.2.16",80))
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP,socket.IP_HDRINCL,1)
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL,socket.RCVALL_ON)


while True:
    output = s.recvfrom(800)
    output1 = convertTuple(output)
    bytearray.fromhex(output1).decode()
    print(output1)
```

Comment: As an aside: `functools.reduce(operator.add, (tup))` don't do this, it is highly inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`recvfrom` returns a tuple of `(data,address)`.  If you want the data in hex just do:

```
data,addr = s.recvfrom(800)
print(address,data.hex())
```

Comment: the problem is it seems to be some encyrpted data. anything i can do about that